# PHP MySQL - Reading months from mysql 'date' column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coming with a question.
I have a table in mysql with several entries:

[ID, TICKET, DATE (YYYY / MM / DD), HOURS WORKED, PRIORITY].

My question is how can I use PHP to show me the sum of all the hours worked in a month?

I want the script to read how many entries there are in a month and show me the name of that month and how many entries there are for that month and year.

For example, if I have 3 tickets in January to show me in a month table (eg January 2022), the next column should be the number of tickets in that month (eg how many entries in the table are from January) and the last column amount all hours worked.

Example:
[image: Exemple]

I'm still trying to learn Php and mysql and I haven't found an example so similar that I can understand and implement it for my problem.

PS. I'm sorry for my English.

Thank you all!

Comment: Let's see what you've done so far so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id_test` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `hours_worked` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `priority` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_test`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

With example content like this:

```
id_test date    hours_worked    priority
1   2022-01-12  2.3     1
2   2022-01-14  4.2     1
3   2022-01-17  2.3     1
4   2022-02-02  4.2     1
5   2022-02-09  1       1
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT count(`date`) AS `cnt_days`, sum(`hours_worked`) AS `sum_hours`, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) AS `year_month` FROM `test` WHERE 1 GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) ASC;
```

Result will look like:

```
cnt_days    sum_hours   year_month  
3           8.8         202201
2           5.2         202202
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I appreciate it! Could you help me with an example of a PHP implementation for this?

Comment: Look here PHP code https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/714b6887319445562a256792eaff0fd5/php/php8/7aed6166a16accabdd19c3488141fd67/